# Apache Camel - I want to read the multipart form data request

Tags: spring-boot, rest, post, apache-camel

Apache Camel - I want to read the multipart form data request so that my Post service can read it and process it ! I cannot find any relevant data for this. Can anyone please guide

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck at something?

Comment: @ShellDragon I am reading the form - data using the HttpservletRequest getParametersMap and then trying to convert the map into json. This json will be the input to the rest post api. Is it the correct way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If your endpoint is using `jetty` component, multipart support is built-in:

> The camel-jetty component supports multipart form post out of box. The
>   submitted form-data are mapped into the message header. Camel-jetty
>   creates an attachment for each uploaded file. The file name is mapped
>   to the name of the attachment. The content type is set as the content
>   type of the attachment file name.